# How to deserialize response from CLI command?

Tags: java, deserialization

I am using Java core to build an adapter that connects to the device to get the data. I get into problems with ***deserializing response data*** from device. I am wondering if we have any way to auto deserialize these data to Java objects in an automatic way?

**Here is the response data**

````
Part Number            : B-292D-HD2
Serial Number          : DAK-031428016165
Firmware Version       : 2.5.6
Firmware Date          : "Feb 28 2020"
Firmware Time          : "15:53:30"
Firmware Options       : "KLV, SRT"
Hardware Version       : --
Hardware Compatibility : -001G
CPLD Version           : 9 (Official, Internal flash)
Boot Version           : "U-Boot 2010.06 (Mar 19 2014 - 10:37:19)-Mankata MF 0.9.14" ```
````

Comment: *I get into problems with deserializing response data from device.* Which are..?

Comment: No, I don’t think there is any automatic way. I wouldn’t find it too hard to write a parser, though.

Comment: Cause I got to work with giant data. if I have to parse every single field to a Java object, It does not make sense. By the way, do you have any suggestions for me to write a parser